# Insert data into SQL Server using C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, database

I have problem with inserting data into SQL Server.

I am trying to add data using C# into my SQL Server database with this code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=DEMO;Initial Catalog=Shipping;Integrated Security=True");
    con.Open();

    cmd = new SqlCommand(
@"INSERT INTO SailorForm 
(  firstName,
   lastName,
   nationallity,
   age,
   gender,
   address,
   deckRank,
   engineRank,
   electricalRank,
   contractdate,
   contractType,
   shipname,
   durationoftour,
   country/port,
   healthissues,
   durationoftour2,
   shiptype,
   Certificateslicenses,
   WorkExperience,
   idnumber
) 
VALUES 
(  @firstName,
   @lastName,
   @nationallity,
   @age,
   @gender,
   @address,
   @deckRank,
   @engineRank,
   @electricalRank,
   @contractdate,
   @contractType,
   @shipname,
   @durationoftour,
   @country/port,
   @healthissues,
   @durationoftour2,
   @shiptype,
   @Certificateslicenses,
   @WorkExperience,
   @idnumber )", con); 

    cmd.Parameters.Add("@firstname", textBox1.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@lastname", textBox2.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@nationallity", textBox3.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@age", textBox5.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@gender", radioButton1.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@address", textBox4.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@deckrank", comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString());
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@enginerank", comboBox2.SelectedItem.ToString());
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@electricalRank", comboBox3.SelectedItem.ToString());
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@contractdate", dateTimePicker1.MaxDate);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@contractType", radioButton3.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@shipname", textBox6.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@durationoftour", dateTimePicker2.MaxDate);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@country/port", textBox11.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@healthissues", textBox13);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@durationoftour2", dateTimePicker3.MaxDate);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@shiptype", comboBox4.SelectedItem.ToString());
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Certificateslicenses", textBox14.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@WorkExperience", textBox15);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@idnumber", textBox7.Text);

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: Your parameter for Country/Port is probably killing it... You can't have a column/parameter with a special character.  If you did, that is just headache coming down the line.  Change parm to something like @CountryPort (same for the column name if that is invalid)

Comment: Thanks for reading all the code i' ll change it and try insert them again.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Is there a thrown exception?

Comment: See [Add](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.add?view=netframework-4.8) method

Comment: Incidentally, I am sure that one year from now all the [age] values will be wrong. Also, that particular parameter should be `cmd.Parameters.Add("@age", Int32.Parse(textBox5.Text));`, if you have already validated textBox5.Text to be parseable as an integer.

Comment: I changed the parameter countryport and now in visual studio throws an exception Unhandled. Object reference not set an instance of an object, System Windows.Forms.Combobox.SelectedItem.get returned null.

Comment: Ok i changed age value.

Comment: Please learn how to normalize data before you continue, because your columns are soon going to go out of sync.

Comment: @TakisPagonis when posting a question, please be more descriptive about what you experience. Ask the question in such a way that it is possible to know what your problem is.

Comment: Ok guys forgive me if i confused you i' m new and it' s my first question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to S/O, don't let others make you feel bad. we all had to learn at one time or another and have all had not-so-great questions.  You made a good first attempt.  You provided your sample code on the connection, insert command and parameterizing.  These were all good things.

Now you will learn more about validating the data to make sure you don't put unexpected garbage in your tables.

Couple suggestions.  When designing your forms, assign the controls better names than textBox1, textBox2, etc, checkBox1, etc...  I'm sure sample to learn, but then looking at code ensures you have the correct code intended.

With fields with date/times, make sure you keep them as that data type, don't try to change to some string value as date filtering will be more of a pain.

Another suggestion, try not to create tables or column names with what COULD be reserved words.  Could be confusing later in development.  If you have a Date column. Do you mean date (as in some function within SQL language)? or TransactionDate - more explicit.  You will learn the common commands soon enough.  Just some food-for-thought while you are learning.

Comment: Thank you very much for all the advices.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void BtnSub_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=DESKTOP-QAE607I;Initial Catalog=DBList;Integrated Security=True");
            string sql = "insert into [user](name,number,username,password)values('"+textBox1.Text+"',"+textBox2.Text+",'"+textBox3.Text+"','"+textBox4.Text+"')";
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
            int countTable = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            if (countTable > 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("succesfull");
                ViewData();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("error");
            }
            
            con.Close();
        }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).